# Appending text from textarea to div on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button that on a click event generates a div. The newly createded div is draggable and stays contained within another div. The issue: As the div is being created I am trying to append text to it. Nothing is getting appended due to not properly grabbing the value from the textarea and appending to the div. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/0wbnud4k/10/)

Jquery

```
$('#button').click(function(e) {
    $('<div class="draggable" class="ui-widget-content"></div>').draggable({ containment: "parent" }).appendTo('.middle-side');
    $('textarea').val().appendTo('.draggable');
});
```

HTML

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Enter Text Here!"></textarea><br/>
 <input type="button" id="button" value="Add Div with Text"/><br/>

<div>
    <div class="middle-side"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you attempting to create HTML content into the `.draggable` div? If so, use Andrew's code below, but use `.html` instead of `.text`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`.text`](http://api.jquery.com/text) instead of [`.appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo):

```
$('<div class="draggable" class="ui-widget-content"></div>')
    .draggable({ containment: "parent" })
    .appendTo('.middle-side')
    .text($('textarea').val())
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/0wbnud4k/11/

Alternatively, perhaps a little cleaner:

```
$('<div />', {
    'class': 'draggable ui-widget-content',
    text: $('textarea').val(),
    appendTo: '.middle-side',
    draggable: {
        containment: 'parent'
    }
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/0wbnud4k/13/

`.appendTo` is a method on the jQuery object. The text you retrieved with `.val` is just a string, and therefore does not have an `.appendTo` method.

Answer (score 0):

You should use text method instead of appendTo and change it as follows:

```
var text = $('textarea').val();

$('.draggable').text(text);
```

you can also check it at:

http://jsfiddle.net/0wbnud4k/12/